# Find the volume of the solid in the first octant bounded by the three surfaces $z = 1-y^2$, $y=2x$, and $x=3$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I want to find the volume of the solid in the first octant bounded by the three surfaces $z = 1-y^2$, $y=2x$, and $x=3$. It seems that would simply be to calculate the following triple integral:

$\int_0^3 \int_0^{2x} \int_0^{1-y^2} z\,dz\,dy\,dx$

This is pretty straight-forward to do without any variable substitutions etc. which makes me think it's almost too simple (for a home assignment).

Am I missing something or is the above correct?

Comment: *Hint*: What is $1-y^2-\varepsilon$ when $y=2x-\varepsilon$ when $x=1$ ($\varepsilon>0$ a small number)?  Is it positive?

Comment: For the first surface $z = 1-y^2$ changes sign at $y = 1$ which is when $x=\frac{1}{2}$ but I'm not sure how that information factors in when doing iterated integration…?

Comment: The easiest "fix" is to change the upper limit of $y$-integral to $\min(2x,1)$, or stick an indicator function into the integrand to kill off these unnecessary parts.

Comment: After integrating over z and y I then end up with the integral $\int_0^3 \left(\frac{1}{2}(\min(2x, 1)) - \frac{1}{3}(\min(2x, 1))^3 + \frac{1}{10}(\min(2x, 1))^5\right) dx$. With these limits, will $\min(2x, 1)$ not always be 1?

Comment: Hmm... why is there a $z$ in the (original) integrand?

Comment: My thinking was that $z$ is the function I need to integrate since no function is given, is that incorrect? Is using the function 1 the correct way to do it? Another idea was to integrate $1-y^2$ as a double integral.

Comment: You should be integrating the function 1 over the region to get the volume.

Answer (score 1):

It's always a good idea to try and figure out how your shape looks, this helps with setting up the right integral bounds.

[image: example image]

Note that calculating the volume using an integral can be written as:

$$ \int_{V}dV = \iiint 1\,dx\,dy\,dz$$

or

$$ \int_{A}f(A)\,dA = \iint f(x,y)\,dx\,dy$$

So using $\iiint z\,dz\,dy\,dx$ is not how you calculated the volume.

The volume bounded by these surfaces could be calculated as:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{y/2}^{3}\int_{0}^{1-y^2} 1\,dz\,dx\,dy = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{y/2}^{3}{1-y^2 \,dx\,dy}   $$

Note that if you want to integrate $x$ at the end, you should split up the integrals as such:

$$\int_{0}^{0.5}{\int_{0}^{2x} 1-y^2}\,dy\,dx + \int_{0.5}^{3}{\int_{0}^{1} 1-y^2}\,dy\,dx$$

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the following (omitting some algebra steps):

$1 - y^2 \geq 0$ when $y \leq 1$ which gives an integration interval $0 \leq y \leq 1$. By dividing the integral into two parts with the intervals $0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq 3$ we get the two simpler integrals:

$V =
V_1 + V_2 =
\int_0^{1/2} \int_0^{2x} \int_0^{1-y^2} dz\,dy\,dx +
\int_{1/2}^3 \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-y^2} dz\,dy\,dx$

$V_1 = \int_0^{1/2} \int_0^{2x} \int_0^{1-y^2} dz\,dy\,dx =
\int_0^{1/2} \int_0^{2x} (1-y^2)\,dy\,dx =
\int_0^{1/2} \left(2x - \frac{8}{3}x^3\right) dx = 
\frac{5}{24}$

$V_2 = \int_{1/2}^3 \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-y^2} dz\,dy\,dx =
\int_{1/2}^3 \int_0^1 (1-y^2) dy\,dx =
\int_{1/2}^3 \frac{2}{3} dx =
\frac{5}{3}$

$V = V_1 + V_2 = \frac{5}{24} + \frac{5}{3} = \frac{15}{8}$

Makes sense? Thank you for the comments.